# paging and sorting using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to use paging and sorting using jquery.I want to embed this with jsp/servlets at back end.

Answer (score 1):

[Ingrid, the jQuery Datagrid.](http://reconstrukt.com/ingrid/)

is a nice jQuery grid with paging and sorting options.

Some more options

[Flexigrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/)

[jQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/) is very good looking

[Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo) is also a nice option